# I have a question about "hardly"

Tags: word-usage

Can I say: "Hardly were there any people at the concert last night" instead of "There were hardly any people at the concert last night"

Comment: You can say it, but you'll sound archaic, poetic, or just plain confused! "There is hardly..." is a set expression in modern, spoken English usage. You can change the tense and number of '"is", but not the word order. Of course, 'hardly' is fine at the start of other sentences: "Hardly anyone was at the concert last night",etc.

Comment: This is not the central adverb usage of 'hardly': 'Hardly had we started when great black clouds began to appear' (or, less poetically, 'We had hardly started[,] when ...').

Answer (score 1):

Certain constructions are used with enough frequency that they establish reader expectations careful writers violate only when absolutely necessary.

*Hardly* at the beginning of a sentence cues the expectation of the [following construction](https://www.englishgrammar.org/sooner-hardlywhen/):

> Hardly had I put the groceries away when John and Carol arrived.
>
> Hardly had we sat down to dinner when the power went out.
>
> Hardly had I begun to read your sentence when I realized you meant something else.

[Checking printed sources](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22hardly%20were%20there%20men%22&lr=lang_en&dcr=0&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&prmd=visn&ei=gxR8WpqCMc_fwQKQ95foDw&start=0&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=748&dpr=1) for "hardly were there" yields essentially [one](https://books.google.de/books?id=CH1cAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA322&dq=%22hardly%20were%20there%20men%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO5JCX_ZXZAhWHmbQKHUcTDwkQ6AEIKTAC) hit, from Hume's *[History of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_England_(Hume))* (1754–61):

> Within ten days, vast quantities or plate were brought to their treasurers. Hardly were there men enough to receive it, or room sufficient to stow it...

This puts your construction in very illustrious but exceedingly rare and archaic company.

On the other hand, constructions such as

> Hardly anyone was at the concert.
>
> There were hardly any people at the concert.

are quite common.

Note that *hardly* is a negative and thus is never negated itself, though in colloquial speech one hears it with some frequency:

> "Did your mom get your sister to go with her to the Manilow concert?"
>
> "Not hardly!"

Comment: Hi @KarlG, maybe I should ask this as a new question, but what does, "not hardly!" mean in your final example? I'd never use it... does it mean "not at all, no chance" or is it more like, "of course, not half"? I have a vague sense that I've heard it used in both (opposite) ways.

Comment: "Not at all!  No way!"